# Insert SQL in VBA got runtime error 3134

Tags: sql, vba, insert

SQL insert statement giving 3134 runtime error. Why?

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

Open "C:\Users\steven.EOPESTATE\Desktop\Sharp Sales\TRMSAVE01.txt" For Input As #1

        Do Until EOF(1)
            Dim TranSQL As String
            Line Input #1, varLine
            testvarline = Split(varLine, ",")
            If testvarline(0) = "$Tran" Then
            Debug.Print testvarline(0), testvarline(1), testvarline(2), testvarline(3), testvarline(4), testvarline(5), testvarline(6), testvarline(7), testvarline(8), testvarline(9)

            TranSQL = "Insert into Transaction ([Tran ID], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [Date], [Time], [9])  Values (testvarline(0), testvarline(1),testvarline(2),testvarline(3),testvarline(4), testvarline(5),'testvarline(6)',# " & Format(testvarline(7), "MM/DD/YY") & "#,# " & Format(testvarline(8), "HH:MM:SS") & "#,testvarline(9)"
            DoCmd.RunSQL TranSQL

            End If

        Loop

Close #1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually trying to insert `testvarline(0)` into `tran ID`, rather than the value, i.e. to simplify your insert statement you are trying to run:

```
INSERT INTO Transaction ([Tran ID])
VALUES (testvarline(0));
```

Which is not valid SQL, you need to build your insert statement properly:

```
TranSQL = "INSERT .... VALUES(" & testvarline(0) & ", " & testvarline(1) & ...
```

So you actually get the values inside your array into the insert statement.

Unfortunately my knowledge of VBA does not extend to using parameterised queries, if this is at all possible I would recommend it as your could by vunerable to [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)